# zoom and pan are not working on the mouse

Tags: interface

Orbiting around objects with the <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd>, or <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> is working, and zooming is working with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd>,

However panning using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> or <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>, and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> are not functioning anymore. Neither is *zooming in/out with scroll wheel*. I've reset to factory defaults and restarted Blender several times.

My system:

> **macOS** Sierra
>   Version 10.12.4
>
> **MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012)**
>   **Processor** 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
>   **Memory** 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
>   **Startup Disk** Macintosh HD
>   **Graphics**
>
> - NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB
> - Intel HD Grphics 4000 1536 MB
>
> **Serial Number** C02J71T5DKQ4

My storage and files are being accessed from an external drive.

Comment: thanks Leander for edit...have restarted my system and tried a new mouse with exact same problem still occuring.

Comment: the edited content in my original post should read "however using SHIFT + ALT + LMB does not work for panning... (I think its been interpreted as shift LMB or opt/alt LMB).

Comment: Why would you even include the serial number of your MacBook, but leave out which version of Blender you're using?

Comment: Just a side note, but I had the same problem. For me it was a tablet update that changed my button allocations.

Answer (score -1):

after restarting Blender many times over 2 days, and loading factory settings, finally decided to try changing orbit turntable to trackball instead, everything worked normally again once I did that. Changed back to turntable and saved to test it, things still working normally. problem solved.(so far). i`ll update this if status changes again.